# Securing my web application against malicious input

Tags: security, xss

I am in the process of building a basic security layer for my web application. I am seeking validation of the steps that I am taking. The current focus is XSS, so I am not touching databases in this post. This is what I have done so far:

1. htmlspecialchars() all user input
2. blacklist certain keywords {"","","text/javascript"} : I am using preg_replace to sub these words with "" instead.
3. Output escaping all dynamic content.

All of this seems like a very trivial security layer. Can anyone recommend better strategies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is too simple. The htmlspecialchars won't help much in every context.

Here is a really good cheat sheet about XSS and what problems there are when you are escaping strings that will be put into HTML.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

Blacklist has it's drawbacks also. Some browsers for example might parse

```
text/javascript
```

and

```
text/java
       script
```

the same way. New line and spaces are removed from the latter and so it get's interpreted like the first one. So blacklist isn't going to be bullet proof method.

Best strategy would be to use some template library that allready handles all this for you. The library must know the context where the string is going. Element value needs different escaping than attribute values.